# Youtube API: difference between videoSyndicated and videoEmbeddable

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

The [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) says:

> The **videoEmbeddable** parameter lets you to restrict a search to only videos that can be embedded into a webpage.

and

> The **videoSyndicated** parameter lets you to restrict a search to only videos that can be played outside youtube.com.

Does it mean `videoSyndicated => videoEmbeddable` or the opposite, or are they complete unrelated parameters?

Comment: did you get any info ?

Comment: still no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Youtube's offical API documentation,

The **videoEmbeddable** parameter lets you to restrict a search to only videos that can be embedded into a webpage.

So according to my experience as a YouTube API Developer, videoEmbeddable means that you can embed these videos outside youtube but they won't play because their owners have menetized their videos and they want their videos to be played ONLY ON YOUTUBE platform where they can earn money from the views, because youtube only counts views played on their official site. So these channel owners are forcing you to come to youtube to watch their videos so that they can earn as much as possible without sharing their content freely.

The **videoSyndicated** parameter lets you to restrict a search to only videos that can be played outside youtube.com.

Whereas, videos with this videoSyndicated parameter set to True are the videos which can be played outside youtube.com as their owners like to share their content even outside youtube without worrying much about monetization.

I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I interpret both sentences these two could be completely unrelated:

- videoEmbeddable: some people do not want their videos to be embedded in an others homepage (e. g. only an official dealer of products of brand X can embed the films of products of brand X) - [and it involves geo blocking possibilities](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en).
- videoSyndicated: I can only assume that company Y does not want to show their product videos on YouTube (confidentiality, ...), but in their own homepage (with restricted access) - but pay YouTube for that service - instead of building an own streaming platform? [Here is something about webview seeming to need syndicate option](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/51404106/embed-does-not-work-on-webview-section-in-application-some-videos-work-some-videos-does-not?hl=en).

What do you think about that?